# Webmin - Associate a subdomain to more than one DB

Tags: mysql, webmin

I'm pretty new to server configuration and I'm stucked with this situation. I have a domain and a couple of subdomain for test. From each one i can connect to the database that have been created toghether with the subdomain. Now i would like to acces another DataBase (created with phpMyAdmin) from one of this subdomains, but my script (it is working) report me that "Cannot Find Database".

Is possible to make this database reachable from that domanain?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this related to Webmin or to your script?

Comment: The script works (I'm sure about this), this is related to Webmin i think, but this is the first time I'm using it so... I can't swear on this...

Answer (score 0):

By default all database in webmin can be access from any site, double check database access I mean make sure your use username have access to this database and some times webmin truncate username go to user and copy it as it's in webmin.